# IndexOutOfRange exception in SqlDataReader in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, indexoutofrangeexception

I am fed up with this error. At the time of login I am authenticating user and then loading some important information in session variables. I hosted my application on IIS and client computers use the application through IP address. Here is my c# code...

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["UserName"] = txtUserName.Text;
        string DefaultYear = GetDefaultFinYear();        
        if (DefaultYear != string.Empty)
        {
            DefaultYear = "connect" + DefaultYear;
            Connections.Init(DefaultYear);
            SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter();
            SqlDataReader dr = null;
            try
            {
                adp = new SqlDataAdapter("CheckLogin_sp", Connections.Connection[Session["UserName"].ToString()]);
                adp.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", txtUserName.Text.Trim());
                adp.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pwd", txtPassword.Text.Trim());
                adp.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("option", "Authenticate".Trim());
                adp.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                if (Connections.Connection[Session["UserName"].ToString()].State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    Connections.Connection[Session["UserName"].ToString()].Open();
                }
                dr = adp.SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();

                if (dr.HasRows)
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {                        
                        Session["Name"] = dr[0].ToString();
                        Session["CompanyName"] = dr[1].ToString();
                        Session["UserId"] = dr[2].ToString();
                        Session["Center"] = dr[3].ToString();
                        Session["ClientCode"] = dr[4].ToString();
                        Session["UserImage"] = dr[5].ToString();
                        Session["CurrentDatabase"] = dr[6].ToString();
                        Connections.BillReport = dr[7].ToString();
                        Connections.DuesReport = dr[8].ToString();
                        Connections.GeneralReport = dr[9].ToString();
                        Connections.PendingReport = dr[10].ToString();
                        Connections.RadiologyReport = dr[11].ToString();
                        Connections.HistoReport = dr[12].ToString();
                    }
                    Session["value"] = "admin";
                    Response.Redirect("~/Masters/home.aspx", false);
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Invalid Password");
                    txtUserName.Text = string.Empty;
                }               
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write(ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                Connections.Connection[Session["UserName"].ToString()].Close();
                adp.Dispose();
                dr.Close();
                dr.Dispose();        

            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid UserName");
        }        
    }
```

Not every time this error occurs but sometimes when multiple computers access the application this error comes on following line

```
Session["Name"] = dr[0].ToString();
```

**Note:-** Once this error occurs it resolve only when the server computer restart.

Comment: How do you authenticate people? Session is based on authentication. Each authenticated user gets its own session. If multiple people login with the same credentials, then it might mess with the session.

Comment: Sorry I can't understand. You can see my code, how I authenticate user. I am sending username and  password to database and if it returns any value I get informations in Session variables.

Comment: Session is user based, but in your case you don't seem to manage the session. Each person that logs in replaces the existing session. That's why multiple users login causes problem.

Comment: Each person login  to application from different computers. So each computer has its own session. Then how latest session will replace the existing session.

Comment: @HenkHolterman You are right. When a request comes and no session id exists, then a new session is created.

Comment: It's super dangerous the way you're caching your connections, and even worse because you are assuming two sessions will never login with the same user account.

Answer (score -2):

I believe wrapping your code in the stored procedure with a transaction would fix your problem.

```
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION CheckLogin 

        --Existing SQL code

    COMMIT TRANSACTION CheckLogin 
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION CheckLogin 
END CATCH
```

All stored procedures called from a web application should use transactions.

Comment: @Clint B this is not database related issue. Indexoutofrange issue related to c# only

Comment: It's been my experience that intermittent unexplainable exceptions  that occur in a web application during a stored procedure call are often caused by the stored procedure not being properly designed for simultaneous use.